# What is "an investment pool"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I googled it but could not find any definition.

> "As part of the opening measures, China pledged to lift foreign ownership in mutual fund management and futures firms to 51 percent by June and remove any limit in three years. Given the massive **investment pool**, if foreign firms can squeeze just a 6 percent share by 2030, that would give them $1.8 trillion in assets under management."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-05-06/global-finance-titans-ready-for-china-s-chance-of-a-lifetime

Comment: "but could not find any definition"? Which word? Also link to the definitions you checked would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you were not looking hard enough. One of the definitions of *pool* found in Google Dictionary (just type in *pool define* in the Google search box and press *Enter*) is this:

> a common fund into which all contributors pay and from which financial backing is provided
>
> "big public investment pools"